# Can we, and should we pin OS threads to CPU cores?

Tags: multithreading, go, cpu

I am programming in Go (and C).
The scenario is: there are per-thread event channels in C.
Sometimes I make cgo calls from Go, post requests to the channel of the current thread.
Completion events come back from the same channel after a few microseconds, and I make cgo calls to poll them back.

Of course when the goroutine that submits a request polls for the completion, it can be in another thread, but let's ignore this issue for now.
My question is: in pure C, we can call `pthread_setaffinity_np` to pin the poller thread to a CPU core to **reduce latency** (assume #threads <= #cores). **In Go, should we do this in the presence of goroutines?**

- If yes, how can we do it? Call `runtime.LockOSThread()` in several goroutines to acquire enough OS threads, and pin them on different cores by cgo calls?
- If no, why?

P.S. I also know a little bit about Go's scheduler (the G-M-P model). However, it seems that M-s are not bound to CPU cores, and P-s has nothing to do with physical cores.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully appreciate your concern here, but in my experience, for what it's worth, threads tend to stay on the same CPU core with no special work required on the part of the programmer.

Comment: The answer to "can you" is of course "yes, using OS-specific routines". Those are OS threads after all, so the OS can do that. The question about whether you should try to pin *goroutines* to *OS threads* is a separate one: you can, via that `LockOSThread` routine, but as you note there's no clear way to deal with the GMP model at that point.

Comment: To @500-InternalServerError: I don’t know what things are in Go, but in pure C, I am pretty sure that pinning threads to cores reduces mean latency and its variance.

Comment: The reasons that LockOSThread exists is/are complex but include the need to make OS-level system calls, where the syscall itself, or series of syscalls, may have to be done on a particular OS thread. The signal stuff on Unix/Linux systems has to do this, for instance. The details of how this affects the rest of the runtime are unspecified and look like they have evolved over time.

Comment: To @torek: Thanks for the comment. I think I understand the necessity of pinning goroutines to OS threads, but it is still unclear to me that whether we should pin OS threads to physical cores.

Comment: I'd say if you care about latency that much, then Go might not be the language of choice. Go isn't a real-time programming language - due to garbage collection and goroutine scheduling, the latency in Go is unpredictable.

Comment: Note that the OS-thread / CPU-core pinning can be done mostly outside the Go runtime system, with Linux and BSD style threading (use cpusets to partition the physical CPUs). I'd bet that if you do this and measure, you'll find it sometimes helps and sometimes hurts performance, in ways that are not predictable without looking at the overall system load.

Comment: To @rustyx: I have to say that is true. However Go is superior to any other language in terms of concurrent programming, so I want to try it. Go now has microsecond-level GC and maybe there are some ways to hide GC time. Also, there are more and more attempts to use Go in latency-sensitive scenarios, such as transaction and storage systems.

Comment: Microsecond-level GC in Go is a marketing gimmick. It's millisecond level in practice, like anywhere else. But anyway you can just test it - lock a goroutine to a thread and then pin it via pthread_setaffinity_np (your bullet 1 essentially).

Comment: `runtime.LockOSThread()` does not grant exclusive use of the thread which it gets wired to. I.e. multiple go routines calling `runtime.LockOSThread()` may still all run on the same thread.

Comment: To @Zyl: I'd appreciate it if you can refer me to some material that proves that. AFAIK `runtime.LockOSThread()` caller exclusively owns an OS thread, ref: https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#LockOSThread

Comment: @IcicleF Might have remembered it wrong then. Would check though what happens when calling LockOSThread from go routines spawned from a go routine which has already called LockOSThread itself.

Answer (score 4):

A call from C to Go uses the caller's thread, so if the C thread is already locked to a CPU it will remain so when it enters the Go runtime. (To demonstrate that property, you can run the program at https://play.golang.org/p/2C9nxyohA91 locally on Linux; the Go Playground doesn't support cgo.)

You can lock a Goroutine to a thread using `runtime.LockOSThread`, and from there you can likely set CPU affinity by calling `pthread_setaffinity_np` using cgo.

But I wouldn't expect that to provide much, if any, improvement in latency: the transition between C and Go already adds a fair amount of latency (due to cache contention updating metadata in the Go runtime scheduler, among other factors). If you're polling on a short enough interval that CPU affinity matters, you're probably going to churn the CPU cache either way; if you're on a long enough interval that it doesn't matter, the effect of CPU affinity will be dwarfed by the effect of the polling interval.

You would probably get more of an improvement by switching from a polling-based approach to a push-based approach: either have the C part of the API block until the request completes (and signal completion by returning to Go), or have the C part call back into Go to notify the original goroutine directly, such as by closing a channel. (In Go 1.17, you will be able to use a [`cgo.Handle`](https://beta.pkg.go.dev/runtime/cgo@master#Handle) to obtain a value you can pass to C to refer to a Go-allocated value.)